# python problem with the import using eval()

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to import a module from different variables with eval, but I don't now why it doesn't work.

```
nameImport = 'essai'
eval('from '+nameImport +' import *')
```

Error:

```
from keyboard import *
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Just import the module, and eval (module.WHAT_YOU_WANT)

Comment: `eval` evaluates expressions, not statements, which is what `from essai import *` is. You could use `exec`, but it would probably be better to use `importlib.import_module`.

Comment: Seconding @chepner: use `importlib` instead; `eval` is scary.